# How to get a button to align to the bottom of a column in the row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to align a Text button to the bottom of a column in a row but everything I'm trying is keeping it aligned to the top of the column.

I have a Container Child → ROW with 3 sections Image, SizedBox, (Column→ Button.)
I want to align the button to the bottom right.

[image]

The alignment properties in the Column doesn't appear to have any effect and are staying with the ROW alignment.
I have tried Align also and still nothing moves

```
CrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
```

Here is my code:

```
Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        child: Image.network(
                          constants.baseImages + snapshot.data[index].logo,
                          width: 80,
                          height: 80,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 215,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(snapshot.data[index].restaurantName),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 2.0, bottom: 2.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  snapshot.data[index].address,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12.0,
                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                  ),
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            child: TextButton(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                foregroundColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                        Colors.blue),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text('More Info'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ]),
              );
```

Can someone explain where I am going wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your last `Column` use `MainAxisAlignment.end`, Also you can include `Spacer` widget and rebuild the app.

```dart
Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
children: [
  // Spacer(), // 
  TextButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      foregroundColor:
          MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      print("more infor ");
    },
    child: Text('More Info'),
  ),
],
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I tried spacer before but then I get 

 The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: how about just using `MainAxisAlignment.end,`? did you provide height for row?

Answer (score 0):

Column isn't required, try

```dart
Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            child: TextButton(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                foregroundColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                        Colors.blue),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text('More Info'),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: That makes no difference to the alignment.